# How to increase resizing corner of textarea in css?

Tags: css, textbox, resize

I need to increase the resizing (right-bottom) corner of textbox for better accessibility.  Is there some way to do it with css?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `::-webkit-resizer` pseudo-element to add styling rules to resizing controls.

```css
::-webkit-resizer {
    border: 2px solid red;
    outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

**Compatibility**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar#-webkit-resizer

Comment: I see, this puts nice borders on invisible resizing corner. Can you increase the width and height of this square corner?

Answer (score -4):

Add the property `resize: none;` to the `<textarea>` element.

Comment: This simply removes the ability to resize it, OP is asking how to increase the size of the resize drag element.